# Como verificar se um checkbox está checado javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema preciso de verificar se um checkbox esta selecionado .
acontece que tenho um formulário com valores que são carregados por pedidos ajax ao servidor. após ter os dados carregados é que ele devia verificar as checkbox como faço isso, tenho de ver se o select estava vazio antes.

```
if (document.getElementById('trabalho').checked) {   

} 
       <div  class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="trabalho" value="trabalho" checked="true" id="trabalho">Trabalho </input>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="residencia" value="residencia" id="residencia">Residência</input>
                    <select  class="form-control" placeholder="Residencia" id="opcao" sytle="display: none!important;">
                        <option value="todos"  selected="selected"> Todos</option>
                        <option value="1antes">1 ano antes</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Ola, Infelizmente não percebi a sua questão. Pode tentar colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Sua condição já retorna true se o checkbox estiver selecionado. da para colocar um exemplo melhor?

Comment: sim ja esta selecionado tenho duas e alterno entre a duas, é para gerar um grafico..

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar essa função para verificar um ou mais checkbox da sua tela se os mesmos estão selecionados ou não. Não sei se é a melhor solução, mas espero ter ajudado.

```
function verificarCheckBox() {
    var check = document.getElementsByName("itemCheck"); 

    for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){ 
        if (check[i].checked == true){ 
            // CheckBox Marcado... Faça alguma coisa...

        }  else {
           // CheckBox Não Marcado... Faça alguma outra coisa...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dava se tivesse onclick mas por defeito ja esta checked.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não sei se entendi muito bem a sua dúvida, mas entendo que você gostaria que houvesse uma verificação se os checkboxes estão selecionados no momento em que a requisição AJAX chega, é isso?

Nesse caso, criei um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nav58bdq/1/) para você verificar o comportamento.

Comment: nao tenho botão nenhum. meu caro ele vai mostrar o grafico todo so depois e que faço filtragem

Comment: Não interessa onde você vai disparar o evento, mas você vai ter que  disparar a requisição ajax em algum momento. O que, para nós, você nao esclareceu é onde você quer disparar isso.

Comment: quero disparar apos verifica se tiver trabalho seleccionado, o que posso fazer é nao ter nada seleccionado por defeito, mas quero mostrar o grafico ja preenchido

Comment: Se você já inicia "TRABALHO" como selecionado, nada impede de você colocar esse evento quando a pagina ou o formulario forem carregados.
Se já está selecionado, então podemos assumir que queremos iniciar o evento.
Outra opção que você pode ter é a de colocar o evento no clique do checkbox.

Comment: sim mas agora a questão não é essa nao me esta a pegar nos valor